# How to keep old data if sqlite version is upgraded?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

How to keep old data if the database version is upgraded ?
Upgrade method I'm using is removing all the data.

```
  @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    String sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table_Name + ";";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(sql);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);


}
```

Comment: why don't you use alter command in sqlite command?

Comment: Use ALTER Table query instead of DROP Table

Comment: check this tutorial, https://riggaroo.co.za/android-sqlite-database-use-onupgrade-correctly/

Comment: if you are not updating Table then no need to use drop table into onUpgrade method, Use ALTER table query if you want to change Table schema. Else you do not need to use DROP TABLE onUpgrade

Comment: @AjayKS could u please give me an example like a code

Comment: @VVB could u please give me an example like a code

Comment: @DharmeshDhameliya could u please give me an example like a code

Comment: @hoabouseif, Check out this example :- https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/how-android-sqlite-onupgrade